# How to get Worker from the IOmniTaskControl?

Tags: delphi, omnithreadlibrary

Is it possible to get the Worker object from a task handle of the type IOmniTaskControl? For example, on a terminate event, I want to log details of which worker was affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IOmniTaskControl` doesn't provide such functionality.

When you create new task, add its implementor and the `IOmniTaskControl` reference to some list/dictionary and then in `OnTerminate` look into that list/dictionary. (And don't forget to remove that entry from the list/dictionary or task controller won't be destroyed as the list/dictionary would keep a reference to it.)

Comment: Thanks. I think just keeping a list of IOmniWorker will also do because then the task can be accessed as its property for comparison.